# calling windows service using silverlight

Tags: silverlight, windows-services

How can i call a windows service using silver light?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a managed service that's in your control, you could host a WCF service in it for silverlight to communicate with.

[Here's how to do that.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Using WCF is, as noted, the simplest solution.  An alternative, if you don't want the (substantial) overhead introduced by WCF, is to use sockets, as demonstrated, for instance, [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/mschwarz/archive/2008/03/07/silverlight-2-and-sockets.aspx).  If you control both sides of the equation, a framework like [SocketsLight](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/SocketsLight-Silverlight-Sockets-Framework.aspx) can take some of the pain out of sockets programming.